# How do i selectively ignore certain .feature files in my build while using karate framework?

Tags: integration-testing, karate

I have to ignore certain .feature test files for my integration test suite using karate framework. Is there any way in which i can selectively exclude certain files.

Comment: This helped me in getting the job done :- https://github.com/intuit/karate#cucumber-options

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the answer is [tags](https://github.com/intuit/karate#test-suites).

Example:

```
@ignore
Feature: my feature

Scenario:
# blah
```

And on the command-line:

```
mvn test -Dcucumber.options="--tags ~@ignore" -Dtest=MyIntegrationSuiteRunner
```

Comment: Can you ignore a single test scenario within a .feature file?

Comment: @wyatt yes. tags can be placed even at a `Scenario` level.