# Is there any way to access individual values of a map of <key, value> pairs in karate if we do not know the value of key?

Tags: integration-testing, karate

Assume that i have the following structure

Content : {
"Key1" : {
   JSON_OBJECT1
}
"Key2" : {
   JSON_OBJECT@
}
}

I need a way to evaluate the schema for all the JSON objects in the content structure and i do not know the value of key at runtime here, is there any way in karate to achieve the same?

Comment: can you accept + upvote this answer please ? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48009361/143475

Comment: upvoted it peter.

Comment: Came up with a generic function to transform my Map<k,v> to object of values and that fixed my issue.
    """
    * def getObjects =
    """
    function(array) {
        var objects = []
        for (var propName in array) {
             var a = array[propName];
             objects.push(a);
        }
        return objects;
    }
    """

Comment: great, I suggest you post an answer below and you should be able to "accept" your own answer and this will help others.

Comment: Done @PeterThomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Came up with a generic function to transform my Map to object of values and that fixed my issue.

```
"""
* def getObjects =
"""
function(array) {
    var objects = []
    for (var propName in array) {
         var a = array[propName];
         objects.push(a);
    }
    return objects;
}
"""
```